# Does ros::shutdown() also stop all Async spinner threads?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, asyncspinner, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might be a very basic question but I couldn`t find an exact answer anywhere . Does the ros::shutdown() command also stop all the Async spinner threads automatically?

I have a lot of blocking functions in my main loop so I created a custom SIGINT signal to close the node as such:

```
void nodeShutdown(int sig)
{
    ROS_INFO("Closing socket connection ...");
    close(client);
    close(s);
    ros::shutdown();
}
```

This doesnt give me a chance to call stop on the spinner. It works but I`m not sure if this is safe. If there is a better way can someone point me towards it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358229/does-ros::shutdown()-also-stop-all-async-spinner-threads?/) by [ashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40706/ashu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @ashu,

If you take a look at the documentation it says: *"[...]  and will automatically stop when it is destroyed"*. Following the code, when you see its destructor [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/spinner_8cpp_source.html#l00204) you will see that the spinner is stopped when is destroyed, that is the same to have a `ros::shutdown()` or SIGINT (Ctrl-C) signal sent since the memory will be freed automatically. And if you do not want to call `ros::shutdown()` you can call directly the destructor.

However to be more clear, in C++ for instance, by default, most signals cause an immediate, abnormal exit of the program but the particular thing in ROS is that `ros::shutdown()` is doing all the nasty work for you.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40706/ashu/) on 2020-08-01**:
Thank you for the clear explanation. This was very helpful.